# Gerund, plural and singular

Tags: grammatical-number

I saw the following sentence:

> Solving math problems gives Peter a headache.

My text said this sentence is following the grammar rule: "V-ing + sing. V"

But I think the sentence is wrong as "math problems" is plural, so shouldn't it be "give" instead of "gives?"

Comment: Is "solving math problems" still plural?

Comment: No, non-finite subject clauses have singular agreement.

Comment: _Problems_ is the direct object of _solving_, not the subject of _gives_. The gerund clause _solving math problems_ is singular, like all clauses. Would you say *_Eating noodles are fun_?

Comment: You've got it wrong in the details of your question. For the subject to be plural, "solving" would have to be plural, not "problems," but like many gerunds, "solving" is an uncountable noun, so as uncountable nouns as subjects do, "solving" takes a singular verb conjugation.

Comment: "Solving" is not an uncountable noun, not a noun at all, but a verb as is evident from the fact that it has "math problems" as direct object. Nouns don't have direct objects.

Comment: Would you say 'Buying cars are expensive'?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Nope, you've got it all wrong. *Solving* is not a noun at all. It's a verb, just like all gerunds always are; they cannot ever be nouns or they stop being gerunds altogether. Its clause is by necessity singular because only nouns can be plural not verb clauses acting as subjects governing verbs of their own.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is "Solving maths problems"  This is a participle clause headed by the verb "solving".  Participle/gerunds are treated as singular when they form the subject of a sentence.

The noun phrase "maths problems" is plural, but it does not head the phrase.  Only the head of a phrase can tell you if that phrase is singular or plural. Gerunds are singular.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not the problems that are giving him the headache, it’s their solving. And *solving* is not plural.